# "IOSurface warning: buffer allocation failed" causes the app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, buffer

While using my ipad app, i got a series of this warning(Mar 18 11:18:06  kernel[0] : IOSurface warning: buffer allocation failed.  980 x 606 fmt: 42475241 size: 2387968 bytes) for more than 50 times in just 20 seconds and app crashed with following report:

```
Mar 18 11:18:35  ReportCrash[1428] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process eDetail[1353]
Mar 18 11:18:35  ReportCrash[1428] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Mar 18 11:18:35  ReportCrash[1428] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/eDetail_2013-03-19-111833_iPad.plist using uid: 0  gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Mar 18 11:18:35  com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.****.profile***[0x1024]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Mar 18 11:18:35  backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.****.profile***[0x1024]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Can anybody help me to figure out the root cause of this problem and resolve it as well.

EDIT: It has been showing that warning at this point of code too:

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
// Get the documents directory


dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);    
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the data file
dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"data.archive"]];

// Check if the file already exists
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath]){

    NSMutableDictionary *dataDict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: dataFilePath];
    if ([dataDict count] != 0) {
        m_cUserName.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"UserName"];
        m_cPassword.text = @"";
        if([[dataDict objectForKey:@"AccountType"] isEqualToString:@"Specialty"]){
            m_cBgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"specialityloginbg.png"];
        }else {
            m_cBgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"infusionloginbg"];
        }
    }   
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: No, nobody can help you because you haven't given us any clues as to what your app is doing.  Perhaps you are getting stuck in a loop that allocates IOSurfaces rapidly?  We have no way of knowing.

Comment: At the moment I was trying to show a bunch of images, when it has given me this report. Afterwards, I am getting this error very frequently and none of images are loading.

Comment: Show that code, then.

Comment: This warning does not seems to be specific to a snippet of code because its happening everywhere I am loading webview full of images or images in simple imageView even.

Comment: Well then you are out of luck.  Nobody can guess what is happening based on this little amount of information.  Try to make an educated guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I got the reason and solution both. Due to over-utilization of memory, OS was not able to allocate buffers for rendering images. After getting a series of this warning, App was crashing. I reduced uses of memory and released objects immediately after finishing their purpose and I got rid of this warning at all.